# Image type webp. The browser load two formats

Tags: html, webp

I have an error in my development when implementing `.webp` and `.png` images.

I don't get the browser to show one option (or another), and now my problem is that the browser loads the two images ( *webp + png* ) gand shows them in block.

I'm doing something wrong, of course, and I'm not sure of img tags either, but I'm using them in `.css`.

Any idea of ​​my mistakes?

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<link rel=preload as=script href="js/modernizr.min.js"/>

<div id="info-1">
  <picture>
    <img class="imgesc" source srcset="img/Camiseta-1.png" type="image/png" width="725" height="1024" alt="imagen">
    <img class="imgesc" source srcset="img/Camiseta-1.webp" type="image/webp" width="725" height="1024" alt="imagen">

    <img class="imgmov" source srcset="img/Camiseta-1-Land.png" type="image/png" width="1024" height="725" alt="imagen">
    <img class="imgmov" source srcset="img/Camiseta-1-Land.webp" type="image/webp" width="1024" height="725" alt="imagen">
  </picture>
</div
```

**Style:**

```
#info-1 img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto
}

.imgmov {
display:none
}

@media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape){
  .imgesc{display:none}
  .imgmov{display:block}
  #info-1{max-width:310px;margin:auto}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing two copies of each image, because you have an `<img>` tag for each image format, including modern ones. That's not quite how fallback images work.

If you're using a `<picture>` element, it should only contain `<img>` elements for backward-compatibility with older browsers. The modern image formats, targeted at modern browsers, should be in a `<source>` element instead.

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Use_modern_image_formats_boldly

Here's the example code from the Mozilla docs, but with your filenames instead:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="img/Camiseta-1.webp"> 
  <img src="img/Camiseta-1.png" alt="imagen">
</picture>
```

That documentation page also talks about how to use the `size` attribute to make resolution-specific fallbacks instead of format-specific ones.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Koster ... I did not take into account some basic details. Regards.